# How to login one time and access in all domain using nextjs?

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, next.js

### How to login one time and access in all domain using `next.js`?

example: Login using `accounts.example.com` and then use it on `something.example.com`, `www.example.com`

How to do that using `next.js` and `firebase-auth`?

If more information needed let me know.

---

#### Edit: 1

---

Some links to make question better:
[Firebase sign in in accounts.example.com and access in something.example.com using react or next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013544/firebase-sign-in-in-accounts-example-com-and-access-in-something-example-com-usi)

Comment: Have you checked [Firebase Authentication sharing between domain and subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69341535/13130697) ? ?

Comment: I fear that this thread is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)  @Kheersagar - can you tell us what it is you are trying to accomplish "functionality wise"?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I already read that. but answer is not much clear for me to understand I don't know what is cloud functions and how to do that?

Comment: @GregFenton For more information you can check this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013544/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013544/firebase-sign-in-in-accounts-example-com-and-access-in-something-example-com-usi). I hope it will make question more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much aware of firebase-auth details but what is the issue here ? You can just set a cookie after user logs into "accounts.example.com" with domain as "example.com" in cookie, so that this cookie will be sent by client to all the subdomains as well and you can use that cookie to validate the user session.

Comment: But how to set it I am using `next.js` and `firebase` how to do that?

Comment: You can go through this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies
In "create session cookie" section while creating cookie you can add domain in cookie options